# How to split the UI into independent, reusable pieces(Components) using react JS

Tags: reactjs

We are very new to React JS. There are lots of debuts/confusions around what should be a component and what should not.

**Is there any guideline available to make this decision simpler?**

For Example, a button displayed many places across the site should be a single component? While attributes of the button like color, dimensions, action, label will be varying.

Comment: yes....Components are generic where the props makes it to display different....

Comment: There are some nice topics like [Presentational vs Container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) (used to be called smart and dumb components), the general idea is that your component should do only what you need it to do and nothing more, to enhance the re-usability of the component. I don't really think your current question is on-topic though

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to decide ahead of time, "Oh, I'm going to reuse this so I'll make it a component." Usually you start with one component, and then break it up later: You start with a component, it gets bigger and bigger, you notice it's getting unwieldy or you've got identical code in places - so you refactor into multiple components.

DRY: When you find yourself repeating the same React code in multiple places, that's when you need a component.

Also, any time you have complicated logic that applies to only one part of your UI, that's another good time to separate it out. Otherwise you will end up with a big jumble of complexity.

I wondered the same thing when I started out. It becomes clearer as you work with React. Give it some time and don't be afraid to go back and refactor.